# Where could I get a VpcLink Id?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I am configuring an API Gateway with CDK (typescript) and currently I have to create an endpoint with HttpIntegration to my EC2 instance running under the VPC.

So I do the next:

```
api.root.resourceForPath("/{pathVar}/smth/{pathVar}")
        .addMethod("GET",
            new HttpIntegration("https://endpoint-from-ec2-under-vpc", {
                options: {
                    connectionType: ConnectionType.VPC_LINK,
                    vpcLink: ???
                }
            }), ...
```

and where could I get the vpcLink?

I tried this way:

```
const vpc= VpcLink.fromVpcLinkId(this, "vpc-link", "VpcID");
```

But during deployment - there is an error: `Vpc link VpcID was not found in account ********`

So **VpcLinkId** is not the **VpcId**, so what is it?

And where can I find it in aws console ore somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

A VPC Link Id is actually from a [VPCLink resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.VpcLink.html).

This resource is a special connection that allows the API Gateway service to connect privately to your EC2/ECS/EKS resources via a load balancer (for REST API this will be a NLB, for the HTTP API it can be an ALB).

Then when referenced in your API Gateway configuration the private connection can be made to the load balancer, so that HTTP traffic does not need to transit the public internet (keeping your resources private).

If you don't need to use any of these private resources you do not need to create this connection, by doing this it does set your API Gateway to be in a VPC it simply creates a link using [PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/).

For more information take a look at the [Set up API Gateway private integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In the aws console,

[image]

In red color

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but to summarize the answer for anyone else looking:

The VPC link ID (which is generated by AWS) you can obtain from one of the properties of the VpcLink object.

```
const vpcLink = VpcLink.fromVpcLinkId(this, "vpc-link", "VpcID");

api.root.resourceForPath("/{pathVar}/smth/{pathVar}")
        .addMethod("GET",
            new HttpIntegration("https://endpoint-from-ec2-under-vpc", {
                options: {
                    connectionType: ConnectionType.VPC_LINK,
                    vpcLink: vpcLink.vpcLinkId
                }
            }), ...
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.VpcLink.html#properties